# ¿Cómo imprimir valores decimales menores a 0?

Tags: c

Cuando mi programa imprime el valor de los años sale en 0 en caso de que el cambio de segundos a años sea menor que 1 año. Cómo le hago para que me imprima los decimales en caso de que sea tipo 0.0657 años y así?

```
/* *PROGRAMA QUE CAMBIA NUMERO DE SEGUNDOS A AÑOS USANDO FUNCIONES* */


#include<stdio.h>

 long Cambiador(long x); //prototipo de funcion

 long seg;
 float anios;

 int main()
    {
     printf("Ingrese los segundos: \n");
    scanf("%d", &seg);

    anios = Cambiador(seg); //llamada de funcion 

    printf("Los %1d segundos son %1d anios",seg,anios);

return 0;
    }

long Cambiador(long x) //definicion de funcion
{
long seg_horas, horas_dias, dias_anios;

seg_horas = seg/3600;
horas_dias = seg_horas*24;
dias_anios = horas_dias/365;
return dias_anios;
 }
```

Comment: Para mostrar en pantalla el dato de una variable `float` debes de usar `%f` en tu `printf`

Comment: El problema es que si defines todas las variables de tipo entero, todas las operaciones, divisiones incluidas, serán enteras y tendrás redondeos. Usa float o double.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este código:

```
double numero = 12345.6789;
printf("El numero en diferentes formatos:\n"
    "Como decimal %d\n"
    "Como valor en coma flotante %f\n"
    "Como valor en coma flotante sin decimales %.0f\n"
    "Como valor en coma flotante con 10 decimales %.10f\n",
    numero, numero, numero, numero);
```

[Produce la siguiente salida](https://tio.run/##jY/LasMwEEXXmq8YHAwJJMZu83abTelfdKNKo0QgzQRZzqb02x23JdBCF1kNXM65lzGLozHDMPFsQm8Jn7psvVSnA4DnjFF7ns7gA5SV/j0Qch8pCT5j8/C4XFXrzXbXgjqnEXbT4jXcAGK03lEiztShkxR1lm7/xgUoVbxIFLRkfNQBS/s7vegg6Us3EjW6IFmPFVi6O6DO8611HC2r@h7JCGNT//Gab3E@mj/fzPH/O2sBVKLcJ8a6hc92GK4):

> ```
> El numero en diferentes formatos:
> Como decimal -271695672
> Como valor en coma flotante 12345.678900
> Como valor en coma flotante sin decimales 12346
> Como valor en coma flotante con 10 decimales 12345.6789000000
> ```

Si quieres imprimir con decimales, deberás usar tipos que soporten ese tipo de números, en [c](/questions/tagged/c) esos tipos son `float` y `double`.